# can't access internet from the docker container runngin ubuntu 14.04

Tags: docker

I am configuring sentrifugo in a Docker container. I can't access the internet from my docker container. I am new to Docker. My host machine is running Ubuntu 14.04. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your container should access internet the same way. Please check your resolv.conf of container and network connective of docker host.